# Can't recover my password

Tags: password-recovery

I've seen this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword but I don't know why, when I'm typing in the fourth step my user name, it appears a message saying that there is not any user with that name, and I'm the only user logged in the laptop?!?
So I can't continue because Ubuntu doesn't accept my user name, anyone can help me?

Comment: Make sure you check /home/ for the username. And also mind Linux is case-sensitive: capitals matter.

Comment: Are you sure you understand the difference between a username (aka login name) and a full name (or display name - as shown on the login screen)? Your username should be a single word, all lower-case: if in doubt, type `ls /home` at the terminal prompt: your home directory will usually have the same name as your user.

Comment: Are you using a system name like "nobody" or "samba"? Try a different name.

Comment: Thank you, it was as "steeldriver" said, i was looking my user name in the wrong place, thank you for everything :)